# C++ Expected unqualified-id when trying to write a function

Tags: c++, header-files

I wrote this code and was just trying to continue writing a function called register. I choose to set it to void because i am not certain if i am going to return anything at the moment. The Expected unqualified-id seems to show up when you put a semicolon in the wrong place, but i cant see that i make that error here..

I tried to comment out the menu.h include and all the three functions i get from the header file. No difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "menu.h"

//From the menu.h header file
int mainMenu();
int customerMenu();
int librarianMenu();

void register() { //Here the error appears.


}

int main () {

int runFlag = 1;
 while(runFlag == 1) {
    int mainMenuChoice = mainMenu();
        if (mainMenuChoice == 1) {
            customerMenu();
        }
            else if(mainMenuChoice == 2) {
                librarianMenu();
            }
        
    
 }



}
```

Comment: `register` is a reserved word.  Use something else.

Comment: `register` is a keyword https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register

Comment: Where "something else" isn't any of the other [keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) either ...

Comment: fwiw, I remember similar question and I can feel with OP, because first time I tripped over this it took me quite a while, though I don't see how the question can be made useful for future readers without anticipating the answer, hence I vote to close as typo